# Not able to click using selenium python webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, click

Not able to click button

```
<p>
    <img class="getdata-button" style="float:right;" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" id="get" onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()">  
    <input type="button" value="Get Results" tabindex="9" id="submitMe" onclick="submitData();" style="display:none" ;="">
</p>
```

Case-1.

```
sub_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='getdata-button']").click()
```

session goes into like hung state (not actually), but nothing happened.

Case-2

```
sub_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='getdata-button']").click()
```

throws error like : `Element not interactable`

Answer (score 0):

For clicking the button, you can do it by the id:

```py
button = driver.find_element_by_id("submitMe")
button.click()
```

Comment: Hi pcampana, tried suggested options but still getting error:selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below solution:

**using ActionChain**

```
button_actual=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitMe")))

actionChains.move_to_element(button_actual).click().perform()
```

or

**Using Javascript click**

```
button_actual=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitMe")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_actual)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Hi Dipak, Thanks for reply, tried options suggested but getting below error.. –Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/untitled1/new_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    button_actual=WebDriverWait(sub_driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitMe")))
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Check if your element in the iframe. If it's then you have to switch to iframe first before handling your above element.